# Free Trial Checkout Page - Add checkbox acknowledging customer agrees to subscription and cancellation terms

Tags: ultracart

Hey StackOverflow avengers,

I'm very new in ultra cart. Guys, please help me with this. My problem is stated below. Please have a look and suggest me some solution.

For customers that "only" have the "free trial product" in their shopping cart, we would like to add a required checkbox acknowledging that they have read and agree to the terms of the free trial in Ultracart. See examples and placements in the attachment.

Should I have to create two different checkout page or there is some other if-else like logic to solve the problem in ultra cart

[image]

Here is the attachment for my Checkout page.

[image]

Thanks, in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkout terms item level configuration is the way to add that into the checkout. Edit the trial item and then navigate to the "Other" tab then click Terms.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more details please find the link for details view.

https://ultracart.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ucdoc/pages/1377105/Configuration+-+Checkout+Terms

Thanks,